# WebRTC screen sharing quality in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I'm using [the following](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) `RecordRTC` demo for recording a video of the user's desktop. When using Firefox, the produced video has correct resolution (in my case, it's 2880x1800). But when using Chrome, the produced video's resolution is only 50% of the original one, meaning 1440x900.

Is there any limitation for video resolution on Chrome, when using screen sharing?

Thanks!

Comment: There are limitation in the Codec that are used by WebRTC, Chrome uses different codecs than Firefox. You have VP8, VP9 and h264.

Comment: Also the whole implementation of WebRTC is made by the browsers themselves, so default settings will differ.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make use the original resolution? I've used all of the codecs you mentioned, and they all generate a smaller resolution.

Comment: You can set the resolution right? I have no experience with desktop capturing,but with camera you can do it.